# Pyodbc.row object to actual value from database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc, ibm-information-server

I am trying to pull data out of an IBM i-Series server (previously AS400) using pyobdc. I am using OBDC Data Source Administrator and iSeries Access ODBC Driver. Here is the code:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};system=SERVER;UID=USER;PWD=PASS;unicode_results=True')
conn.setencoding('utf-8')
c1=conn.cursor()
c1.execute("""select TEST from TESTER.ITEMTEST where TEST='005911'""")
<pyodbc.Cursor object at 0x02A1F460>
rows = c1.fetchall()
print(rows[0])
```

This is what is returned:

> (b'\xf0\xf0\xf5\xf9\xf1\xf1@@@@@@@@@', )

From what I've read, this is a pyodbc.Row object. I've searched the internet high and low and cannot find anything that solves my problem.

One of our systems developers in house said maybe there is some sort of setting in the OBDC Administrator that I need to change, but everything seems to be setup properly.

Here are some screenshots of the OBDC Administrator and how I have the driver setup:

[Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5aKw.png)

Is there a way to convert the pyodbc.Row object to the actual value contained within the database? Or is there something else I am missing?

I have tried:

```
rows[0].TEST
```

and it still returns a pyodbc.Row object. All I would like to do is return the actual value retrieved from the server and not a pyodbc.Row object.

When I use:

```
c1.description
```

I get:

```
(('TEST', <class 'bytearray'>, None, 15, 15, 0, False),)
```

The actual value I should get is: 005911

Comment: If you are only selecting a single column from a single row just use `fetchval()` instead of `fetchall()`

Comment: I tried `fetchval()` and it returns **240**

Comment: When you do `thing = c1.fetchval()` what is `type(thing)` ?

Comment: `type(thing)` returns `<class 'bytes'>`

Comment: Okay, and what is `repr(thing)` ?

Comment: `repr(thing)` is `"b'\\xf3\\xf2\\xf0\\xf3\\xf7\\xf5\\xc3\\xc1@@@@@@@'"`

Comment: Weird. How about `rows = c1.fetchall(); thing = rows[0][0]` - Do `type(thing)` and `repr(thing)` stay the same?

Comment: `type(thing)` returns `<class 'bytes'>` and `repr(thing)` returns `""b'\\xf3\\xf2\\xf0\\xf3\\xf7\\xf5\\xc3\\xc1@@@@@@@'"'"`. I am trying this with differn't serial numbers. In this instance I tried 320375CA. You can see 320375 after the "xf"s. The "CA" isn't visible. I have no idea what this means.

Comment: Since you're running Windows you can use [this VBScript](https://pastebin.com/KeB07161) to test your ODBC connection without involving pyodbc. If you get the same results as your pyodbc test then it is a driver issue and not a pyodbc issue.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the connection line and it fixed everything. All I had to add was: TRANSLATE=1

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};system=SERVER;TRANSLATE=1;UID=USER;PWD=PASS')
```